# How would I display something if a variable is met?

Tags: php, session

So, I would like to display a badge on a users profile, if they have been defined as an $admin in the config file.

At the moment, I have been trying this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']==$admin)
{
?>
<img src="default/images/role_moderator.gif" alt="moderator" />
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<img src="default/images/role_empty.gif" alt="empty" />
<?php
}
?>
```

However, it just displays on every single profile. Does anybody know a way to fix this?

Cheers

EDIT: config.php

```
<?php
/******************************************************
------------------Required Configuration---------------
Please edit the following variables so the forum can
work correctly.
******************************************************/

//We log to the DataBase
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('forum_database');

//Forum Staff
$admin='The_Darthonian'; // For admin forum features

/******************************************************
-----------------Optional Configuration----------------
******************************************************/

//Forum Home Page
$url_home = 'index.php';

//Design Name
$design = 'default';


/******************************************************
----------------------Initialization-------------------
******************************************************/
include('init.php');
?>
```

FURTHER EDIT: I am trying to display an icon on users profiles that have $admin defined in the config.php

Comment: `<?php echo "show what you want to show"; ?>` this is a basic syntax are looking for this..?

Comment: Please explain it more clearly. What is `$admin`? Also, are the images displayed in every page or a particular page? What's in the config file you just mentioned?

Comment: I've added some more things to the post, hopefully that'll help some more

Comment: In which file do you start the session? Do you start it at all ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: OOOOH, yes, 'include config.php' is at the start of each file.

Comment: OK, try starting the session in your config.php. Add session_start() at the beginning of your config file. And post the code where you set the $_SESSION['username']

Comment: I found the problem with the code above. It basically means that if you are defined as $admin, you see the moderator badge, however, if you are not, you can't. I need to attach the code to a users profile, instead of to a session.

Comment: My profiles go like this: http://localhost/forum/profile.php?id=1, and I have a varible called userid (of course). Maybe there is a way that I could make it so if they have a userid of 1 show it on their profile?